# Flutter: Ant : You must not specify nested elements when using refid

Tags: flutter, junit, ant

On my flutter project by using [junitreport](https://pub.dev/packages/junitreport) I am making junit report but it is XML,

```
 flutter test --machine | tojunit --output test.xml
```

Now by Ant, I want to make Html from it. test.xml is at the root of my project, here I made build.xml:

```
<project name="genTestReport" default="gen" basedir=".">
  <description>
    Generate the HTML report from JUnit XML files
  </description>

  <path id="classpath">
    <pathelement location="/opt/homebrew/opt/ant/1.10.12/junit/junit-4.13.2.jar"/>
  </path>
  <target name="gen">
    <property name="genReportDir" location="${basedir}/unitTestReports"/>
    <delete dir="${genReportDir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${genReportDir}"/>
    <junit printsummary="true" showoutput="true" fork="true">
      <classpath refid="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}">
          <include name="test.xml"/>
        </fileset>
      </classpath>
      <formatter type="xml"/>
    </junit>
    <junitreport todir="${basedir}/unitTestReports">
      <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="test.xml"/>
      <report format="frames" todir="${genReportDir}/html"/>
    </junitreport>
  </target>
</project>
```

Now I run this command in root folder:

```
alt@Alis-MBP rr-front % ant -buildfile build.xml
Buildfile: /Users/alt/Projects/rr-front/build.xml

gen:
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/alt/Projects/rr-front/unitTestReports
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/alt/Projects/rr-front/unitTestReports
BUILD FAILED
/Users/alt/Projects/RentReady/rr-portal-front/build.xml:13: You must not specify nested elements when using refid
```

Does it seem I need some configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

The `<junit>` task is just for running the tests, which you already did outside Ant. So I think you only need the [`<junitreport>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html) in this case to convert the xml to html.

The reason for the error is that you put the fileset inside the classpath in the junit task:

```
<classpath refid="classpath">
  <fileset dir="${basedir}">
    <include name="test.xml"/>
  </fileset>
</classpath>
```

When you use a refid, as you have in the classpath, you are saying "use this reference to define the classpath".  Hence, if you use a refid ***and*** define the classpath with nested elements, there is a conflict.

Comment: I changed to this: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/K2qmb4sw2M/ but I got this error `[junitreport] the file /Users/alt/Projects/rr-front/test.xml is not a valid testsuite XML document`

Comment: @CyrustheGreat - no idea... Could be a different version of junit used by Ant versus source of report?

Comment: I don't know , I am using this version, Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.12 compiled on October 13 2021

Comment: You'd need to look into the xml itself to figure out why Ant's junit isn't happy with it.

Comment: I changed my test.xml to this https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/ThwDxPZ5wJ/ , without ", but still I have problem